# PHP syntax error in WordPress theme function

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a change to the language text used in the following function in my client's WordPress website's theme function file and now a 500 error is being thrown and the following error is logged in the server log. **PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'd' (T_STRING)**. The error is being reported on line 145, which is the $args['title_reply'] bit. The text changes I made were to the "Share" text. I am not sure what could be causing the error, as nothing is standing out visually. I have tried deleting, then retyping all of the function, but that failed to work. Maybe fresh eyes can spot the culprit.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_comment_for_args', 'bourncreative_comment_form_header' );
function bourncreative_comment_form_header($args) {
    $args['title_reply'] = '<h3>Share Your Comments & Feedback:</h3>';
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: That code there would not cause a syntax error.

Comment: It's likely further up the page, having a missing quote or something

Comment: Yeah, that is what has me baffled. The website was working fine until I edited the function file. I edited it first using the built-in WordPress editor, then I switched to FTP and Coda. Would the built-in editor have caused something to mess up?

Comment: Yes I guess it's possible. Try to re-upload the file using FTP. You might have some strange characters in there.